# How to set cookie to not allow another submission of form?

Tags: forms, cookies, submit, delay

I need a to know how to set up a cookie to not allow a user to submit a form twice. After one submit they should get a JavaScript message that says "Can not submit form again" or something like that. Maybe a time delay where they can't submit the form after 10 days or so. Also it also can't interfere with the validation of the form or sending the user to the confirmation page on the first submit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _If_ you're using jQuery, [this cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) may help.